# Empty View does not display "No results behavior" for admin

Tags: views

I have a **View content pane** with a setup to display "`Header`" when there is content and "`No results behavior`" when the view is empty.
The view works fine for authenticated and anonymous users, however it always shows the "`Header`" instead "`No results behavior`" for empty view to the admin.

Looking at the html output for the view, I see an empty table with one empty row is being generated for admin, but not for `authenticated or anonymous users.`

In the view table settings, all empty columns are set to hidden. All fields have hide empty checked with no rewrite. The views has a contextual filter to display no results when filter is missing.

Its baffling that the view works for others except admin.
Any tips will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I had somewhat complex filter criteria that was causing the issue for admin. 
One would think that this should not cause an issue, but it seems to.